# Circuit breaker + panel selection -- make and breaker series?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

Is there a compelling reason to choose one type/brand of breaker & panel (Eaton CH, Eaton BR, Square-D QO, Square-D HOM, Siemens, GE) over another when putting a new electrical panel and breakers in?  Or is availability (I am loading my panel with dual-function CAFCI/GFCI breakers on *all* 15 and 20A branch circuits, provided no shared neutrals turn up that is) the sole consideration I should take into account when deciding on one brand of breakers over another?

Comment: Question: WHY would you possibly need/want AFCI/GFCI breakers for ALL circuits???

Comment: @SpeedyPetey -- I'm in a house with 50+ year old electrical wiring and want maximal protection -- GFCI throughout is needed simply to conform to Code due to the lack of EGCs in 99.9% of the wiring, and arc fault protection is mandated in several places (bedroom, kitchen, laundry, living/dining) and seems (to me) like a wise idea throughout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am of the strong opinion that for a residential application it almost does not matter what brand you choose. They are all nearly the same, even QO and CH series. Sure, copper buss is nice, but not mandatory. I have seen and installed pretty much every major brand in the last 25 years or so, they are ALL ok.

I would choose something that you can get breakers and parts locally and easily.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall avoiding "Square D Homeline" due to possible issues with the copper over aluminum buss bars. I considered trying to get an "interchange/nonproprietary" brand having seen some folks with obsolete panels flailing to find breakers, but ended up with Square D QO as both available, affordable and with a solid copper buss. I hope it turns out to be "non-niche" enough that I don't have problems down the road.

Apparently it's possible that [one has to specify copper buss even on QO (there seems to be an option for that) or it varies by model and even some homeline units have copper buss.](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1626663.pdf)

Comment: Unless you are in a highly corrosive environment, such as very close to a coastline, an aluminum buss is absolutely fine.