# Does code require that you use only breaker brands explicitly listed on the breaker box, or are "compatible" breakers compliant?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

To be clear, there's another version of this question of, "If some random off-brand breaker fits, is it acceptable?" We already know the answer is no to that.

As an example, the Westinghouse breaker panel lists 2 acceptable breaker brands: 1) Westinghouse, 2) Bryant.

Eaton states in it's description / specs, that it is listed as a compatible breaker to Westinghouse brand.

The question here is that if a breaker brand, like Eaton, *formally* states that it's compatible with Westinghouse, then is it ok to substitute breaker brands not explicitly listed (on the breaker panel) as acceptable?

Comment: Answer may be found here https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/131728/46271

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A panel is listed to work with certain breaker *lines*, regardless of whether they change hands

When UL tests a panelboard (loadcenter, to us) to the UL 67 standard and gives it its listing, they test it with the breakers the panelboard is *listed & labeled* to be used with, in various combinations.  However, the fact that a breaker line changes corporate parentage does not change the design of the breakers themselves, and as a result, a panel listed to work with a breaker line back in the 1950s is nominally compatible with breakers from that line made in 2019.  In other words, your Westinghouse/Bryant BR loadcenter is compatible with BR breakers, no matter whether they were made by Bryant, Westinghouse, Cutler-Hammer, or Eaton.

There are also UL *classified* breakers, which go through the same testing with the panelboards they are documented (labeled) to be compatible with, but at a later point in time.  This is how Eaton can make a breaker (their type CL) that can be used in Murray/Siemens and GE panels, for instance.  However, this classification process is *not necessary* if a breaker comes under the loadcenter's listing, as an Eaton BR breaker does for the listing of your Westinghouse box.

Answer (score 4):

At least in the US, The governing authority on this matter is the Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratories (NRTLs), such as UL.  The breaker panel itself is **UL Listed** to work with the breakers on its label.  However, other brands can make compatible breakers and submit them to UL testing to ensure they work safely, and then these breakers become **UL Classified** for use with that panel, and are legal to use.  Eaton's CL (CLassified) line is one example of this -- Eaton formally stating they're compatible means nothing, what matters is that UL stated that they're compatible based on their independent testing.

Comment: Thanks for this - I called Eaton directly and they said that they were UL Classified to be used in Westinghouse panels.