# Comparison of dual function breakers brands

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

This is a follow up to this [breaker and panel selection](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61748/circuit-breaker-panel-selection-make-and-breaker-series) question.

Apparently, there are gfci  [failures, and differences between outlet and breaker protection](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2017/09/05/its-time-we-update-ul-943-again/). In particular, gfci breakers are not required to have the same (as much) functionality as gfci outlets.

So! Is there any documented comparison, between the different brands (Siemens, Eaton, Schneider,...), of  the quality/implemented functionality of arc, ground, and dual function, fault breakers? I have not seen any, but...

Comment: What type of panel will you be putting these in?  It matters.

Comment: @Harper I'm in much the same situation as the person in the first post. I am changing the load center anyway, and  am 'free' to choose whichever load center (and corresponding breakers) I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "documented" comparisons you will find will come from the manufacturers themselves comparing their products against the others, the value of which becomes immediately suspect. For the most part, UL listing dictates that they all follow the same basic rule and pass the same tests. Everything after that is opinion and people's opinions tend to be formed by their personal experiences. I have installed all of the major manufacturer's products and quite honestly, there isn't a hair's width difference in them in them from a hardware standpoint. The biggest differences come in the form of availability in your area and customer service, which will also vary by location. I would ask around at your available suppliers as to what they carry in stock then ask neighbors about their experiences in terms of customer service.

In my opinion the article on differences between GFCI breakers and GFCI receptacles is a little disingenuous. They refer to breakers not having to meet the same requirements, but then go on to say that one of those is the "line to load reversal" test. Swapping line and load is something that is impossible to do on a plug-in breaker! They also go on about the possible failure modes, but a breaker is ALREADY a disconnecting device, so there is no need to do a redundant test on its ability to disconnect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and certainly I should have noticed (on my own) your breaker/receptacle observation...BTW,  I noticed afterwards https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150771/siemens-spring-clip-and-bus-bar-not-compatible?rq=1 which mentions, cough, a 'hair's width' difference... FWIW, we are replacing an ITE panel, so my inclination was to use Siemens.

Comment: ITE is Siemens now (since 1983), there is no difference. For the most part, Siemens has not changed anything substantial from the original ITE designs, most of the part numbers are even still the same..

Comment: Again, thank you for your time. I gather you're not inclined to take to heart the worry expressed in the link of the Siemens GFCI breaker not fitting properly on the stab?